# Too Much Webkit, crashed mobile safari?

Tags: mobile, safari, webkit

I appear to have uncovered a dilemma, and I wonder if anyone else knows about it. It would appear that significant use of webkit effects to replace JQUERY functions for CSS3 enabled browsers appears to crash mobile safari to the desktop.

Has anyone else encountered this problem / a solution for it. Or is it caused by someone else.

Comment: Please post a detailed example of how to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @Sparky672 I have a web page that will do it. I hope that is sufficient. http://www.golfbrowser.com/courses/mill-ride/

Comment: I'm on a third gen iPod Touch which is really the low end for iOS 5 compatibility.  Your site is slow but Mobile Safari did not crash.

Comment: iOS5 is definitely crashing. It was built with iOS5 in mind too. What with the -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch applied everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'm encountering a similar problem. In my case, applying -webkit- tranforms or transitions on hundred's of dom elements causes mobile safari to crash on ios5. interestingly enough, when I test on an old iphone 3g, (ios3) mobile safari does not crash.

I know this has something to do with the -webkit- prefix, because I'm using SASS for the css, and commenting out the webkit line on my 'browser-prefix' mixin, which is responsible for adding the webkit prefix to all the css declarations, fixes the problem.

I've tried to override the webkit prefixs by setting all the -webkit- values to 'none' within media queries, but it seems that the crash happens even before the values get overridden.

I'm also certain that it has to do with the amount of DOM elements on the page, since this page with lots of elements crashes, http://dev.moovylist.com/jasiu

whereas this page with the same css, but less elements, does not crash. 
http://dev.moovylist.com/suzy

My only solution thus far is to load a seperate webkitless stylesheet for the iphone, so that the iphone never sees the webkit prefixes.

Comment: I'm experiencing webkit and CSS3 related crashing on iPhone 4 iOS 5.0.1. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166441/drawing-to-a-css3-3d-transformed-canvas-on-iphone4-causes-hard-freeze It does not crash on the new iPad (5.1) or the two other iOS devices I have (iphone 3gs on 4.0 and ipod touch 1g on 3.1.3). Will mobilesafari apply 3D CSS3 transforms without the `-webkit-` prefix?

Comment: Thanks. Removing the webkit prefix solved the issue for me. It didn't even matter that I had the non prefixed transform after the webkit prefixed transform. I had to remove it completely.